# Mapping DIVs to Vimeo/Youtube time stamp

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, vimeo

I'm currently trying to map some several divs to different timestamps of a Vimeo/Youtube video and jump to certain time stamps. I understand that with videos embedded directly into HTML, I can use currentTime in JS to track and manipulate the timestamps. However, is there something similar for Youtube/Video videos and if so, how do I do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo has two methods available with its player library, setCurrentTime and getCurrentTime, that are documented here: https://github.com/vimeo/player.js#getcurrenttime-promisenumber-error